# Some addplot modifications needed

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have some questions regarding a plot I wanna create.
Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            width=\textwidth,%Breite des Plots
            axis line style=thin,%Achsenstärke
            axis y line = center,
            axis x line = center,
            no markers,%keine Markierungen auf den Plots
            every axis plot/.append style={thin},%Plotstärke
            axis on top=false,%Achsen hinter dem Plot
        ]
        \addplot table[col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {1}]{124-Auswertung.csv};
        \addplot table[col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {2}]{124-Auswertung.csv};
        \addplot table[col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {3}]{124-Auswertung.csv};
        \addplot table[col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {4}]{124-Auswertung.csv};
        \addplot table[col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {5}]{124-Auswertung.csv};
        \addplot table[col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {6}]{124-Auswertung.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result: [image]

The csv-file is here (too long to add here): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57816350/124-Auswertung.csv

Since only the first plot is a measurement and the second to sixth plot are just signals, I wanna rename the plots on the y-scale like shown below.

Is there a way to mark a specific area like shown in the picture below? 
I would like best to have the marking area in the CSV-file. How would I do that?

Is there a way to have the col sep... and the pgf/number/... as period ... option more globally?

Since I will have a lot of quite similar plots in the document I would like to predefine the colors of the plots (the color option doesn't seem to work when I add it to every single plot)

How to change the color of the axis?

What I wanna achieve:

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}% <-- added

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
width=\textwidth,%Breite des Plots
axis line style=thin,%Achsenstärke
axis y line=left,
axis x line=middle,
no markers,%keine Markierungen auf den Plots
%every axis plot/.append style={thin},%Plotstärke
%%axis on top=false,%Achsen hinter dem Plot
ytick={-6,...,1},% <-- added
yticklabels={$v_5$,$v_4$,$v_3$,$v_2$,$v_1$,-1,0,1},% <-- added
% only for demonstration ...
trig format plots=rad,
domain=0:4*pi, samples=48, 
xmax=4.1*pi, ymax=1.2
        ]
        \addplot    {   0.5*sin(x)};
        \addplot    {-1+0.5*sin(x)};
        \addplot    {-2+0.5*sin(x)};
        \addplot    {-3+0.5*sin(x)};
        \addplot    {-4+0.5*sin(x)};
        \addplot    {-5+0.5*sin(x)};
        \addplot    {-6+0.5*sin(x)};
\scoped[on background layer] \fill[red!30] (2.5,-6.5) rectangle (3.5,1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For demonstration of solution I use `sin` function which you can simple replace with your table.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. If I have further questions, I'll come back later.

Comment: Why are the last two plots dashed, I try to make them solid but the usual solutions (\addplot[solid] or every axis plot style/.append ...) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In the my answer `addplot` use line styles from predefined list of styles. See pgfplots manual, section *4.7.7 Cycle Lists -- Options Controlling Line Styles*, page 210. Probably the *color list* style offer what you looking for. Otherwise, you can define line styles individually as option in `addplot` (as you have in your question) . If this problem still persist, than seems to be the best way ask new question, which will be as question better visible to wide audience who can help you.